# EXPRESS js : Urls giving incorrect contents

Tags: node.js, express

I have the node server server.js and two other js files where am fetching data courses (courses.js) and reviews (reviews.js)

**`Server.js`**

```
  const express = require('express');
 //import express from 'express';

 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 //import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

 const pino = require('express-pino-logger')();
//import pino from 'express-pino-logger';

 //const courses =require('./courses');
//import courses from './courses'
//import *  as courses from './courses';

var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
 app.use(pino);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());




 //Get all reviews

 const reviews= require("./reviews");

 app.get("/reviews", async(req,res)=>{
 console.log(reviews);
  let result =  await reviews (req.headers);
  res.send(result);
 });



 //REST API Call

 app.get("/",async (req, res)=>{
 res.send("Hello Node,js ! Change the authorization header in the courses&reviews. Put in your 
   Authorization token from udemy affiliate api-2.0 ")
 }) 


 //Get all courses

 const courses= require("./courses");

 app.get("/courses", async(req,res)=>{
 console.log(courses);
  let result =  await courses (req.headers);
  res.send(result);
  });


  app.listen(PORT, () =>{
    console.log(`Server is started and listening on port: ${PORT}`)
 })
```

courses.js

```
 const fetch = require('node-fetch');

 url = 'https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses';


     module.exports=  async  function courses() {
    try{
     const request= await fetch(url,{
            method:'GET',
            credentials:"same-origin",
            headers:{
            "Authorization":"xxxxxxxxx",
            "redirect":"follow",
            "referrerPolicy":"no-referrer",
            "Permissions-Policy":"interest-cohort =()",
            "Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*",
            'Content-Type': 'application/json,  charset=utf-8',
            "credentials":"same-origin",
            "cache":"no-cache"
            }
           
            
            
         })
          .then(function(response){
              //console.log(response)
              return response.json();
          })
          .then(function(data){
             // console.log(data);
             return data;
          })
        return request;  
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log("We have an error")
        console.log(e)
    }
     }
```

reviews.js

```
  const fetch = require('node-fetch');

  url = 'https://www.udemy.com//api-2.0/courses/1723848/reviews';


     module.exports=  async  function reviews() {
    try{
     const request= await fetch(url,{
            method:'GET',
            credentials:"same-origin",
            headers:{
            "Authorization":"xxxxxxx",
            "redirect":"follow",
            "referrerPolicy":"no-referrer",
            "Permissions-Policy":"interest-cohort =()",
            "Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*",
            'Content-Type': 'application/json,  charset=utf-8',
            "credentials":"same-origin",
            "cache":"no-cache"
            }
           
            
            
         })
          .then(function(response){
              //console.log(response)
              return response.json();
          })
          .then(function(data){
             // console.log(data);
             return data;
          })
        return request;  
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log("We have an error")
        console.log(e)
    }
   }
```

When I visit /courses I get the course content but when I visit /reviews I get still get the course content . Sometimes the contents reverse and I get reviews on both urls

Comment: are you using express js to render the html?

Comment: Please Provide your all code ;-)

Comment: Can you post your `reviews.js` and `courses.js` file contents?